# MSHTML: Click on menu button make it disappear if the menu panel is narrow

Tags: html, vba, excel, web-scraping, mshtml

I've been trying to pull an excel spreadsheet from a database using MSHTML class in VBA. In doing so, I had to click on different buttons and type a phrase in the search box, etc. I managed to do them without an issue.

In the picture below you can see the environment I'm working with.

[image: Work environment]

The red box on the right is showing you a handle in which you can drag it around to resize the search panel. If the search panel is tiny, you should click on the side arrow bar to make the Actions button visible (makes sense).

I can click on the Actions button and then click on the Export List to File button without encountering any problem if the search panel is wide enough, but no if it's narrow (where you have to take that additional step). See below picture:

[image: Actions Menu]

If the panel is narrow, when I click on any of the buttons on the Actions drop down menu, the whole thing disappears. Thus, I can only hover and I couldn't find any methods other than click. This is what I get when right click on Export List to File button and select inspect:

```
<li class="liClass" id="liID">
    <a class="aClass" id="aID" hidefocus="true" href="javascript:var abc = doNothing()" unselectable="on">
        <img class="imgClass" id="imgID" src="SourceURL">
        <span class="spanClass" id="spanID">Export List to File</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

As you see, there is no button object. I thought maybe that has something to do with the issue, but why is the methodology works in one case and not the other?

This is the code I'm using to click on the desired button:

```
Dim ExportButton As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim ExportButtons As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Set SearchElement = Nothing

While ExportButton Is Nothing
    Set ExportButtons = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("span")
    
    If Not ExportButtons Is Nothing Then
        
        For Each SearchElement In ExportButtons
            
            If SearchElement.innerText = "Export List to File" Then
                Set ExportButton = SearchElement
                Debug.Print ("Export List To File is identified!")
            End If
            
        Next SearchElement
        
    End If
Wend

Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:03 AM#)

ExportButton.Click

Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:03 AM#)
```

I'd appreciate if someone could help me to solve this problem. I'm new to programming in general and started learning VBA a few months ago.

Best,
Arman

---

Answer (score 0):

If you resize the "search panel" you may have to reset your `HTMLdoc` reference before setting your `ExportButtons` collection.

Comment: I like the resetting HTMLdoc idea, but it didn't work.
Unfortunately, I can't resize the search panel. There is no user interaction during the process. The macro is supposed to do everything automatically. I tried updating the HTMLDoc variable by placing a replica right before I click on that Export button, but it didn't resolve the issue; the drop down menu disappeared...

Comment: @armani time to research how to get around the unselectable=on attribute lol